# If we call main.async while on a background queue when is the code executed?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Calling `main.async` while on a background thread to run UI code that should be handled by the main thread appears to be a standard practise.

When we call `main.async` while on a background thread and the main thread is busy with normal code that's not used any GCD calls (I assume this is equivalent to `main.sync`?) when is this code executed?

Is the regular main.sync code executed first or will our main.async code be executed and how does this work? How can a single queue execute asynchronous and synchronous code at the same time?

Playground Example: (The A array is printed but B array isn't)

```
let a = "a"
let b = "b"
let aArray = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a]
let bArray = [b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b]

for letter in aArray {
    print(letter)
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    print("Entered background thread")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Left background thread")
        for letter in bArray {
            print(letter)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably in the next runloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between enqueuing code on main using `sync` and `async` in term of when the code will be executed - in both cases the code will be executed as soon as it will become the first one in the main thread's queue. There is a queue of tasks that are supposed to happen on the main thread. You added something on that queue. When everything that was enqueued before your code will get executed, your code will get its turn, regardless if you added it using `sync` or `async`.

The only difference is in what happens with the calling thread - with `sync` the background thread becomes blocked until the code on the main thread will get executed; with `async` the background thread will continue.

Just a sidenote here - never call `DispatchQueue.main.sync` on main thread - it will cause a deadlock.